# Two functions with only two points of intersection

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $f, g$ are functions so that $f''(x)>0$ and $g''(x)<0$ forall $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ an $g$ have only two points of intersection.

Comment: I presume you mean 'at most two points of intersection'? (For example, $f=\exp,g=-\exp$ have no intersection.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Then $h$ is twice differentiable and  $h''(x)>0$ for all $x$ and the claim is that $h$ has at most two zeroes.
Assume $a<b<c$ and $h(a)=h(b)=h(c)=0$
Then at some point $u\in (a,b)$ we have $h'(u)=0$ (Rolle). Also for some $v\in(b,c)$ we have $h'(v)=0$. Then in some $w\in(u,v)$ we have $h''(w)=0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f$ and $g$ have at least three points of intersection: $x<y<z$.

Then the function $h:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $h(t)=f(t)-g(t)$ is convex, $h''>0$ and we have $h(x)=h(y)=h(z)=0$.

Using convexity of $h$, we know that the function $$\tau_y:\mathbb R\backslash \{y\}\rightarrow \mathbb R, t\mapsto \dfrac{h(t)-h(y)}{t-y}$$ is increasing. 
But $\tau_y(x)=\tau_y(z)=0$ hence for any $t\in [x,z], t\neq y,$ we get $\tau_y(t)=0$ thus $h$ is constant on $[x,z]$ (on $[x,z]\backslash\{y\}$ at first and then apply continuity of $h$) and is equal to $h(y)=0$.

This shows you that a convex function having three zeros $x<y<z$ has to be identically zero on $[x,z]$.

In particular, $h''=0$ on $[x,z]$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\phi = f-g$ satisfies $\phi'' >0$ hence is strictly convex.

Let $N=\{x | \phi(x) = 0 \}$.

If $N$ is empty, then  there are no intersections.

If $N=\{x\}$, a single point, then there is one intersection (at $x$, of course).

So suppose $N$ consists of two or more points, that is, there exist $x_1,x_2 \in N$ with $x_1<x_2$ such that $\phi(x_1)=\phi(x_2) = 0$.

Since $\phi$ is convex, it must have a minimum in  $[x_1,x_2]$. Suppose $\xi \in [x_1,x_2]$ is a minimizer. If $\phi(\xi) =0$, then we must have $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x \in [x_1,x_2]$ which contradicts $\phi$ being strictly convex. Hence we must have $\phi(\xi) <0$.

Now let $x \in (x_1,\xi)$, then $x = (1-\mu) x_1+\mu\xi$ for some $\mu \in (0,1)$. Then $\phi(x) \le (1-\mu) \phi(x_1)+ \mu \phi(\xi) = \mu \phi(\xi) < 0$. Similarly we obtain $\phi(x) < 0 $ for $x \in (\xi,x_2)$. That is, between any two points of $N$, $\phi$ is strictly negative. It follows that $N$ can have at most 2 points.

Note the result holds if only one of $f,g$ are strictly convex (as $\phi$ wll still be strictly convex).